# Could not load... (error) in Problem set 5 of CS50 when check50

Tags: c, cs50

I'm at the problem set 5 of the CS50 course : speller. To solve this problem, we need basically to load a dictionary (already given by the staff members)into a hash table that we need to create. Then, we have to check if there are errors in a text (also given) by using the hash table. (Errors -> words that aren't in the hash table). Finally, the program is supposed to free all the memory allocated to load the dictionary and show the "misspelled words (errors) on screen". After that, to check if there are errors in our program, the instructors included their answer to the problem (not their program, but the misspelled words that their program found in the text).
Personally, I wrote a program that gives the same answer as the one that the staff members' does. But when I try to check it using check50 (instructors created it to check automatically whether our program is well written or not), I get those :

> Expected Output:
> MISSPELLED WORDS
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
> WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1
> WORDS IN TEXT:        1

> Actual Output:
> Could not load min_length/dict.

> Expected Output:
> MISSPELLED WORDS
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
> WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1
> WORDS IN TEXT:        1

> Actual Output:
> Could not load max_length/dict.

> Expected Output:
> MISSPELLED WORDS
> foo's
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     1
> WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1
> WORDS IN TEXT:        1

> Actual Output:
> Could not load apostrophe/without/dict.

> Expected Output:
> MISSPELLED WORDS
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
> WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1
> WORDS IN TEXT:        8

> Actual Output:
> Could not load case/dict.

Oh yeah ! I forgot to tell you that the instructors already wrote the majority of the program : we only need to implement the following functions :

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = LENGTH * 'Z';

// Hash table
node *table[N];


// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    //Get the hashcode for the word
    int hashcode = hash(word);
    //Create a pointer which is going through the linked-list
    node *trav = NULL;
    //pointing to the first element of the linked-list
    trav = table[hashcode];
    //Go through the linked-list
    while(trav != NULL)
    {
        //if found the corresponding word in the hashtable
        if(strcasecmp(trav -> word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //pointing to the next node
            trav = trav -> next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    //creating an integer to store a value
    //insert here
    int value = 0;
    //adding the value of all the characters in the word
    int n = 0;
    while (word[n] != '\0')
    {
        value = value + toupper(word[n]) - 'A';
        n++;
    }
    if (value < 0)
    {
        value = (value) * -1;
    }
    return value;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    //Creating a string storing a word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    int check = 0;
    //Open dictionary file
    FILE *ptrDico = fopen(dictionary, "r");
     if (ptrDico == NULL)
     {
        printf("The pointer to the dictionary result in NULL.\n");
        return 1;
     }
    //Read strings from file one at a time
    while(fscanf(ptrDico, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        //Create a new node for each word
        node* newWord = NULL;
        newWord = malloc(sizeof(node));
        //Put the word into the node
        if (newWord == NULL)
        {
            free(newWord);
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy(newWord -> word, word);
        //Hash word to obtain a hash value
        int hashcode = hash(word);
        //Insert node into hash table at that location
        newWord -> next = table[hashcode];
        table[hashcode] = newWord;
        check++;
    }
    //check if loaded successfully
    if (check > 1)
    {
        fclose(ptrDico);
       return true;
    }
    fclose(ptrDico);
    return false;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    unsigned int count = 0;
    //Creating a pointer that is going to go through the linked-list
    node *trav = NULL;
    //Going through the array of linked-list
    for (int list = 0; list < N; list++)
    {
        //Going through the linked-lists
        trav = table[list];
        while(trav != NULL)
        {
            trav = trav -> next;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    //Creating a tmp pointer and a free pointer
    node *tmp = NULL;
    node *freeNode = NULL;
    //Going through the linked-lists to free them one at a time
    for (int list = 0; list < N; list++)
    {
        //Pointing the free pointer to the first element of the linked-list
        tmp = table[list];
        freeNode = table[list];
        while(tmp != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp -> next;
            free(freeNode);
            freeNode = tmp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I really don't understand what's going on here (I'm a real beginner as you would have guessed), so even the tiniest contribution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Submit some simple "hello world" program and see if you are still getting these `Could not load min_length/dict.`. Looks to me like the checker is broken (in this case it will eventually get fixed)

Comment: Where are the instructions?

Comment: @n.1.8e9: I believe the instructions are [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/5/speller/).

Comment: You've decided that `load` should return `false` on success and `true` on failure. May I ask why? This is a rather unorthodox choice. The instructions apparently don't tell one way or the other, but I would be very surprised if the authors actually meant that choice.

Comment: @n.1.8e9: The function `load` returns `true` when `check > 1`, i.e. if more than one word was loaded from the dictionary. Therefore, as far as I can tell, that part of the code is correct. However, you are correct that the two `return 1;` statements are probably wrong. They should be `return false;`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes these were confusing me.

Comment: regarding:  `newWord = malloc(sizeof(node));
        //Put the word into the node
        if (newWord == NULL)
        {
            free(newWord);`  when the call to `malloc()` fails, then there is nothing to pass to `free()`

Comment: regarding: `while(fscanf(ptrDico, "%s", word) != EOF)`  Much better to compare against 1 rather than EOF

Answer (score 0):

Read the check50 results carefully and critically. How many words are in the dictionary of the failed tests? Is that number greater than 1 (as in `if (check > 1)`)?